# Select values in specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's use the below table as an example:

```
tableId
1
2
3
4
```

I want to select first values that have tableId equal to 1 or 2, if none rows are selected then 3 or 4.

I could use the below select statement but it would cover only the first condition:

```
SELECT tableId
FROM exampleTable
WHERE tableId = 1 OR tableId = 2
```

What should I add to the query to make it work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT tableId
FROM exampleTable
WHERE tableId IN (1, 2)
UNION ALL
SELECT tableId
FROM exampleTable
WHERE tableId IN (3, 4) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM exampleTable WHERE tableId IN (1, 2));
```

Here is an alternative method, using `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
select top 1 with ties
from exampleTable
where tableId in (1, 2, 3, 4)
order by (case when tableId in (1, 2) then 1 else 2 end);
```

`top with ties` returns rows while the `order by` keys are the same.  By using a `case` in the `order by`, you guarantee that the sort keys are the same for 1 and 2, and for 3 and 4.

Comment: I'm just curious. Can you write this with ISNULL() or COALESCE()?

Comment: I don't see a natural way to incorporate those functions into the answer to this question.

Comment: Curiosity from me too here - why the NOT EXISTS part of the first example?  Sorry if a silly question.

Comment: Okay. I would do something like your first example if I should do it. I was just thinking if this were a case where they were useful.

Comment: @MatRichardson . .  Because the OP only wants 3/4 when 1/2 does not exist in the data.